# AVAudioplayer retrieving nil argument for NSURL

Tags: objective-c, ios, avaudioplayer, nsurl

Hi there I am using the following snippet of the code.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"mtgcko" ofType:@"caf"];
    [audioPlayer initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    audioPlayer.delegate = self;
    [audioPlayer play];
```

It should work but on my device and simulator I receive the following error :

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'`
but the file I'm calling in the NSURL exist in MainBundle.

Don't have any idea where could be the problem. 
I read in some articles on web that the problem could be in codecs?
But this seems not to be, because I am able to play all other formats including aiif, mp3, wav ...

Comment: Try printing out the value of `path`, the file may not exist in that location.

Comment: if i print it i receive nil, but physically i can see the file in main bundle:(

Comment: Is it placed in a directory (sub folder)?

Comment: no but if i play mp3 from the same - no problem

Comment: It could be that it hasn't been copied to the bundle correctly. Click your app's target in Xcode, then select Build Phases and look at the Copy Bundle Resources list to see if your file has been added or not. If not, add it there.

Comment: correctly added already checked...